# VS error c2600 after merge branches

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I got a very confused issue that after i merged my working branch into master, a C2600 error is generated by VS2012 C++ compiler with no presage

my current code is something like:

```
//in head file
class myBase{  }; //abstract

class myDerive : public myBase{
    myDerive();
    ~myDerive();
};

//in cpp file;
myDerive::myDerive(){}
myDerive::~myDerive(){}
```

and also the weird is, this head file & cpp file are both untouched in the working branch.

And warning was generated by git showed that `LF will be replaced by CRLF`

Comment: In this code I don't see any problem which can cause this issue, might be your original code has one. Because this problem only occurs when you try to define some compiler-generated special member function without declaring them..

Comment: that's why i confused because this part of code is untouched but error report is here.

Comment: CR or CRLF are both whitespaces, so no impact.  Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd577fyk.aspx I'd rather look at includes, and at myBase (which seems not to be fully described here).